# What is the easiest way to use the Drag Cursor for all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I refer to this cursor:

[image]

I was searching and I found that for Mozila Firefox it's simple, just by add `cursor: -moz-grab` to the `css`. And for others browsers it's required to import an `.cur` file and even using `JavaScript`.

But for other browsers What is a good way to use that cursor without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tan;
}
div:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
div:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sometimes don't lose the effect of "active" when you release the mouse. Perhaps working with `document.onmouseover` helps.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - The OP said _"without using JavaScript"_, so gave a CSS solution.

Comment: But you using javascript in your example, see this `ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '')">`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - That has nothing to do with the cursor. I did that to recreate the dragging effect.

Comment: I understand, it may be that your javascript that causes the problem. But I think only with the dependence of JavasScript (using `document`) could be possible to cause a better effect.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - It works fine without the `ondragstart` event. You were right, it was causing the problem.

Comment: Nice! :) Great example +1

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I'd only add the `-moz-grab` and `-moz-grabbing` for Firefox. For IE I did not found a simple way to do. For more info [here](http://www.jaycodesign.co.nz/css/cross-browser-css-grab-cursors-for-dragging/)

Answer (score 1):

The `grab` cursor is unofficial and thus not widely supported. You can however use a custom image as a cursor, even with a fallback to the `grab` cursor for browsers that support it. Something like this:

```
#dragMe {
    cursor: grab, url('hand.cur'), default;
}
```

There is plenty of information about this out there. Something like this for example: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/

Comment: `grab` is defined as a possible value of [`cursor`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#cursor) in CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI)
Editor’s Draft.